# Получить введённое пользователем значение input

Tags: javascript, input

Вроде всё просто, но всё же. Хочу получать значение из поля ввода, но получаю `undefined`. Вот код:

```js
var Name = $("loginField").val();
function log_in_click(){
    alert(Name);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\Repositories\Сайты\MyWebSite\style.css" />
  <script src="D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\Repositories\Сайты\MyWebSite\script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="loginField" placeholder="Login..." value="">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="passField" placeholder="Password..." class="inputs">
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="log_in" class="button_login" onclick="log_in_click()">Login</a>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) $("#loginField")  2) необходимо подключить jquery

Comment: @soledar10 как его подключать?)

Comment: размещать в head или перед </body> - https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Comment: @soledar10 без изменений

Comment: пример https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/j8w630Lx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, сначала стоит изучить, как это сделать без jquery

```js
function log_in_click(){
    alert( document.querySelector("#loginField").value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\Repositories\Сайты\MyWebSite\style.css" />
  <script src="D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\Repositories\Сайты\MyWebSite\script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="loginField" placeholder="Login..." value="">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="passField" placeholder="Password..." class="inputs">
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="log_in" class="button_login" onclick="log_in_click()">Login</a>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вроде бы отлично. А можете в ответ написать почему мой вариант не рабочий?

Comment: var Name = $("loginField").val(); => var Name = $("#loginField").val();
в любом случае, забыли поставить #

Comment: и подключить jquery

Comment: да и ещё. Почему у меня в подсказках (VSCode) нету `value`. Только `nodeValue`

Comment: Хотя код с value работает, почему его нету в подсказках

Comment: Вероятно, редактор думает, что Вы пишите для nodeJs, покажите полный скриншот файла с кодом, открытый в VS Code

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0YoI.png

Comment: Хм. А даже с переменной ваш Вариант не работает.

Comment: Может я не так подключил jquery

Comment: jquery подключили?

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/d2d2cc100066dcd23d5c2c5097c6cb9b

Comment: Вероятно, редактор думает, что Вы пишите для nodeJs, покажите полный скриншот файла с кодом, открытый в VS Code
.
Файла Js

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/4dd4079f0f04a5e9deb1b909339f5dda

Comment: Странно но я не смог понять как занести значение из поля ввода в переменную